# What does mc:Ignorable="d" mean in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What does `mc:Ignorable="d"` mean in WPF?

And this row:

```
d:DesignHeight="500" 
d:DesignWidth="300"
```

Answer (score 129):

The [`mc:Ignorable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024.aspx) namespace provides xaml definitions that are "ignored" by the xaml processor.

This allows you to specify information used by the designer at design time which is ignored at runtime.  In your case, you can specify `DesignHeight` and `DesignWidth`, which are not "real" properties on a `Window`, but work in the designer for providing a default design time experience.

Answer (score 39):

`mc:Ignorable="d"` sets `d:` prefix as a mark for attributes used in design. Read more on MSDN: [`mc:Ignorable` Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024.aspx)

`d:DesignHeight="500"` and `d:DesignWidth="300"` use that `d:` prefix, what makes them available only during design time - they are ignored after standard program compilation.

Comment: No, `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` sets `d:` as a prefix for attributes used in design. `mc:Ignorable="d"` just causes these properties to be ignored during runtime.

Answer (score 12):

This a predefined `namespace` in WPF to be used in design-time,r but will be ignored when actually compiled and executed. It will display your design-time choices but has no effect on the actual layout.

There is an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130730215413/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/02/01/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml.aspx) on the topic.