# How to stretch XAML controls within a page

Tags: wpf, xaml

This has been bugging me for awhile now. I'm having trouble getting my grids and/or borders stretch to be the height and width of a xaml page. By default both VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment should be set to 'Stretch' however they only want to stretch only to the height of the child elements I have inside them and I don't know why.

Example: If I have a WPF XAML Page with a fixed width of 1024 and height of 768, then to me the following code should display a grid that stretches the width and heigth of the page, it works correctly in width but not height. In fact it only works correctly for width because I'm specifying a hardcoded width.

```
 <page ..
  ...
  ..
  d:width="1024" d:height="768">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition height = "*" />  
      <RowDefinition height = "50" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition width = "250" /> <!-- Left Side Navbar !-->
      <ColumnDefinition width = "*" /> <!-- TabControl !-->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border grid.column = "0">
       <Textbox></Textbox>
    </Border> <!-- Vertical should stretch !-->

    <Border grid.column = "1">
       <TabControl></TabControl> 
    </Border>
  </Grid>
```

I put the background color of the page to green just to see if the page itself was stretching to the screens full height and it wasn't, it only vertically stretched to the extent of the control child elements within the grid. I should be able to set a grid or border to stretch both height and width even without any elements inside of it, can someone show the true correct way to do this?

Comment: This works fine for me - can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: whats d:width and d:height? u mean d:DesignWidth? even then they are Design time only values. Have no effect on run-time

Comment: d is probably set to ignorable which means that what you hard coded
is not the real height and width 
Hard code Height and Width and not d:Height and d:Width 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749584/what-does-mean-mcignorable-d-in-wpf

Comment: Yea that was the solution, I did have the ignorable set, and I also the <frame> tag that host the page also had a VerticalAlignment that was set to 'Top'. Thx for help guys